# Solr bad return type error

Tags: java, solr, error-handling

I am trying to use a basic Solr tutorial and I am getting an error I have neither seen before nor can find details about online.

My code is:

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SolrjPopulator {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SolrServerException {
    HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
    for(int i=0;i<1000;++i) {
      SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
      doc.addField("cat", "book");
      doc.addField("id", "book-" + i);
      doc.addField("name", "The Legend of the Hobbit part " + i);
      server.add(doc);
      if(i%100==0) server.commit();  // periodically flush
    }
    server.commit(); 
  }
}
```

and the console error I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient; @62: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @62
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams', 'org/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager', 'org/apache/solr/common/params/ModifiableSolrParams', 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: bb00 0359 2ab7 0004 4db2 0005 b900 0601
    0x0000010: 0099 001e b200 05bb 0007 59b7 0008 1209
    0x0000020: b600 0a2c b600 0bb6 000c b900 0d02 00bb
    0x0000030: 0011 592b b700 124e 2d2c b800 102d b0 
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@47,Object[#127])

            at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.<init>(HttpSolrClient.java:186)
            at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.<init>(HttpSolrClient.java:159)
            at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.<init>(HttpSolrServer.java:30)
            at com.coba.efx.news.server.SolrPopulator.main(SolrPopulator.java:14)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
            at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

In addition, the class `HttpSolrServer` seems to be "deprecated". I don't know what that means exactly, but can someone tell me what the problem is and if it's possible to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post a dump of the full dependency tree? Also, which is the Java runtime? Is it an Android application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HttpSolrClient has a [constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj/5.1.0/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient.java#HttpSolrClient.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%2Corg.apache.http.client.HttpClient%29) that accepts an HttpClient. When not passed, it creates an internalClient that is a CloseableHttpClient.

So you can create a Default client and pass it as follows..

```
SystemDefaultHttpClient httpClient = new SystemDefaultHttpClient();
HttpSolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient(url, httpClient);
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  I have no idea why that worked, but it fixed the problem I encountered.

Comment: Glad i could be of some help :) Lets mark the issue as solved so that others can find it easily.

Answer (score 3):

It's somewhat difficult to understand exactly what the problem is without being able to reproduce it. Anyway, it seems that a Solr method returns a `DefaultHttpClient` that is **not** a `CloseableHttpClient`, which is really weird because a quick look at the sources tells that in fact `Default***` is a grandchild of `Closeable***`.

However this trace is all we have: I guess your project has a (direct or indirect) dependency on some version of Apache httpclient that is incompatible with the one Solr was compiled against. You should dump the full dependency tree and ensure there's only one version.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Raffaele. What do you mean dump the dependency tree exactly? Do you mean the jars? I am not using Maven btw.

Comment: If you are not using a dependency manager, sill try to dump all the JARs on the compile and run classpath (maybe Intellij dumps the classpath as the first line of the stdout when you run a project)

Comment: If you are using maven of managing your project. You can you the following command: mvn dependency:tree. Redirect the output of this into a text file and find the different versions of httpclient package.

Comment: Well this is known version mishmash see here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7948

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely problem with more versions of httpclient in classpath.
I had the same issue with SolrJ version 6.6.0, so I switched to version 7.0.1 and got another "version" exception:

Error: INSTANCE

```
INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id attempt_xzy, Status : FAILED
Error: INSTANCE
```

in yarn logs:

```
ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: 
Error running child : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient$Builder.withHttpClient(Lorg/shaded/apache/http/client/HttpClient;)Lorg/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/SolrClientBuilder;
```

If you are using Maven the solution is to use [shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) and make fat jar like this:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>${main.class.full.name}</Main-Class>
                                    <Build-Number>1.0</Build-Number>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                          <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>org.apache.http</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>org.shaded.apache.http</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

**NOTES:**

1.
Make all other dependencies provided by cluster classpath provided

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

2. How to find version issues:

   - `yarn classpath` or
   - echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH or
   - `find /usr/hdp/current -type f -name "*httpclient*"`

You will see something like this:

```
./hadoop/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar
./hadoop/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
./hadoop/lib/ranger-hdfs-plugin-impl/httpclient-4.5.2.jar
./ranger-hdfs-plugin/lib/ranger-hdfs-plugin-impl/httpclient-4.5.2.jar
./hadoop-yarn/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar
./hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

In case any one else is having this error it may be due to how your application is setup, especially if you have multiple referenced projects.

For me, I was receiving this issue every time I started the main project and couldn't figure out why. (View jar files on build path):

[image: included jar files]

These jar files were also being deployed as part of the Deployment Assembly. I also have a referenced project being deployed. The issue was that this referenced project was also deploying the same solr-6.6.1 jar files, thus causing error to appear.

This is a bit of a edge case, but hopefully it may help someone.